# randomizing mcq in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to generate random question and answer.

Here's the aspx code

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Here's the vb code

```
Public Property Counter() As Integer
    Get
        Return IIf(ViewState("counter") Is Nothing, 1, CInt(ViewState("counter")))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        ViewState("counter") = value
    End Set
End Property
Sub question()
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From questionbank Where id=@Idquestion", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idquestion", Counter)
    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader
    dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Try

        While dr1.Read()
            Me.lblSoalan.Text = dr1("question")
            Me.RadioButton1.Text = dr1("rightanswer")
            Me.RadioButton2.Text = dr1("wrong1")
            Me.RadioButton3.Text = dr1("wrong2")
            Me.RadioButton4.Text = dr1("wrong3")

        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have a set of question. User need to click next button to move to another question. I want the system to randomize the question everytime user attempt to answer the same set of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to randomize the ID of the question before the `SELECT` statement is executed. Replace your `Counter` when a random value. Use `CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * n))` to get a random integer value between 0 and N (inclusive)

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idquestion", CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * n)))
```

Comment: it is working however the problem is the question is keep on randomizing eventhough i didn't click next button and how to make sure the answered question will not repeated when the user click next button?

Comment: There are basically two ways to get rid of repeats:

**1.** [**Create a list, make random selections from that list and remove each item as you select it.**](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=393023)

**2.** [**Create a list, randomise it, then select items from it from first to last.**](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=585813)

Comment: It's only randomize the questions. How about the answers?

Comment: The same. You'll need to randomize `"rightanswer"`, `"wrong1"`, `"wrong2"` `"wrong3"`. I would use the indexes as integer instead the column name

Comment: is there another way to randomize the "rightanswer", "wrong1", "wrong2" and "wrong3" without being repeated?